# converting svg to base64 url

Tags: svg, base64

i need an icon url for my project and i have an svg file such as :

```
<svg viewBox='-100 -100 200 200'>
    <g transform='rotate(-90)'>
        <path d='M0,0 L61.73,-38.268 A100,75 0 0,1 61.73,38.268 Z' fill='param(fill) #FFFFFF' stroke='param(outline) #000000' stroke-width='param(stroke-width) 0.25'/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

i converted this svg to base64 by using online converter as :

```
PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSctMTAwIC0xMDAgMjAwIDIwMCc+PGcgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSdyb3RhdGUoLTkwKSc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTAsMCBMNjEuNzMsLTM4LjI2OCBBMTAwLDc1IDAgMCwxIDYxLjczLDM4LjI2OCBaJyBmaWxsPSdwYXJhbShmaWxsKSAjRkZGRkZGJyBzdHJva2U9J3BhcmFtKG91dGxpbmUpICMwMDAwMDAnIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0ncGFyYW0oc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoKSAwLjI1Jy8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Logkd37/

but it just doesnt work. can someone explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: you're missing the svg namespae on the root svg element and all those param things aren't valid either.

Comment: but it works just like this https://jsfiddle.net/f9tpzn2x/  can you please give some more hint

Comment: That's inline SVG in HTML, it has different rules.